# Scaladocs build fails kafka

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, apache-kafka

I am trying to build Apache kafka from source as explained [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka) using gradle but I am not able to get scaladocs to build. Following is the error log for same:

```
 == Expanded type of tree ==

ConstantType(value = Constant(kafka.utils.timer.TimerTaskList))

uncaught exception during compilation: java.io.IOException
File name too long
two errors found
:core:compileScala FAILED
:core:compileScala (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 1 mins 4.416 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileScala'.
> Compilation failed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 13.736 secs
Stopped 1 compiler daemon(s).
Received result 

CommandFailure[value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.ReportedException:org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':core:compileScala'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=5656, address=[4d0d3e79-f94a-43ca-b183-792d2bfe1a95 port:55666, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=1f1f4b55-9da9-4283-b361-8b0bfce3f208,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle,daemonRegistryDir=/home/akshat/.gradle/daemon,pid=5656,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}.
```

Though I suspect it is a memory issue but I do not see any place of altering it. I tried editing here:

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false

    configure(scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions) {
      memoryMaximumSize = '1g'
      jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
    }
  }
}
```

But it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused due to my home folder being encrypted. It seems that kafka has trouble installing in encrypted folders. I had to reinstall ubuntu to solve this. There is no other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is probably related to Gradle memory settings. You can increase the Gradle heap by setting the environment variable: `set GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` (Windows) and it might work better.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Any idea on "File name too long"

Comment: export GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx1024m for Ubuntu.

"File name too long" is probably just what it sounds like and due to Scala class name mangling. Linux has a hard limit on the total path length so you could try to move the project further up in the file system, closer to / and see if that might help.